# If I were to take an old Windows 95 .EXE written in C++, and I wanted to convert 8bit Integers to 16bit Integers, would it be difficult?

Tags: c++, assembly, assemblies

If I had an old PC game that has certain variables that cannot exceed 255 without crashing, would it be possible to convert ALL 8bit integers into 16bit integers by modifying the Windows 95 executable?

The game I'm talking about is Total Annihilation from 1997. And although the game itself was way ahead of it's time and had the capabilities to be modded into epic experiences, (Hell, the game was so ahead of it's time, the data files use JSON-like syntax... The game also supports 4K and looks amazing still.) there is unfortunately a limit to the total number of weapons in the game. All weapons have IDs, and the max ID of a weapon is 255 as can be seen below:

```
[NUCLEAR_MISSILE]
    {
    ID=122;
    name=Nuclear Missile;
    rendertype=1;
    lineofsight=1;
    vlaunch=1;

    model=ballmiss;

    range=32000;
    reloadtime=180;

    noautorange=1;
    weapontimer=5;
    flighttime=400;

    weaponvelocity=350;
    weaponacceleration=50;
    turnrate=32768;
    areaofeffect=512;
    edgeeffectiveness=0.25;

    energypershot=180000;
    metalpershot=2000;

    stockpile=1;
    targetable=1;
    commandfire=1;
    cruise=1;

    soundstart=misicbm1;
    soundhit=xplomed4;

    firestarter=100;
    smokedelay=.1;
    selfprop=1;
    smoketrail=1;
    propeller=1;

    twophase=1;
    guidance=1;
    tolerance=4000;

    shakemagnitude=24;
    shakeduration=1.5;

    explosiongaf=commboom;
    explosionart=commboom;

    waterexplosiongaf=fx;
    waterexplosionart=h2oboom2;

    lavaexplosiongaf=fx;
    lavaexplosionart=lavasplashlg;

    startsmoke=1;

    [DAMAGE]
        {
        default=5500;
        ARMCOM=2900;
        CORCOM=2900;
        }
    }
```

Would this be worth it at all to attempt? I'm not very familiar with Assembly language, but I've heard that with C++ you sometimes have to write your own assembly language in certain instances back in the day.

All I want to do is just bump up all 8bit Ints to 16bit by editing the .EXE, how difficult would this be to pull off?

Comment: Very difficult -- I'm tempted to say impossible.  Even if you could change the opcodes, you'd still face the problem that changing the sizes of the ints would necessarily also mean changing their locations in memory (to allow the additional bytes some place to fit), so you'd also need to update all the code that computes memory locations of variables as well.  I think the closest you'd get is by decompiling the binary back to assembler, then rewriting the assembly code, but even that would be extremely difficult.  Finding a copy of the original C++ source code is the only practical approach.

Comment: No, there's no way this would be doable in any reasonable amount of development time.  TA probably used a fixed-size table to store weapon definitions.  Even if you could change the variable that records the length, and all the code everywhere that looks at *it*, you'd still have to find all the places where looping over the table was hard-coded.  IDK, maybe you could just increase it to 512 entries, but that size is probably hard-coded all over everywhere.

Comment: I'd highly recommend that you just **check out the open-source rewrite of TA, called [Spring RTS](https://springrts.com/)**.  The TA unit definitions and graphics are of course copyrighted, but there are some mod packs for Spring that use them (or look exactly like original TA, and have the same unit names).  See https://springrts.com/wiki/Games#TA-derived

Comment: Try to get source code of the game, otherwise very very difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> All I want to do is just bump up all 8bit Ints to 16bit by editing the .EXE, how difficult would this be to pull off?

Essentially impossible without access to the source code. Replacing an 8-bit integer with a 16-bit one would change the size and layout of the data structure which contained it. Any code which "touched" those objects, or any objects which contained them, would need to be updated. Identifying that code would be an extensive project -- in all probability, it'd require most of the game to be *manually* decompiled to C source code.

Comment: @Matt: Basically: if need to ask this question, you don't (yet) have anywhere near the skills to do it.  Even then, it would probably take months to years of effort without the original source.